# Lclassname.classname; cannot be cast to classname.classname

Tags: java

i'm writing a program for a game called 'Trivia'. Below is the source code:

Trivia.java

```
public class Trivia implements Serializable  {
private String question;
private String answer;
private int points;

public Trivia() {
    question = " ";
    answer = " ";
    points = 0;
}

public String getQuestion() {
    return question;
}

public String getAnswer() {
    return answer;
}

public int getPoints() {
    return points;
}

public void setQuestion(String q) {
    question = q;
}

public void setAnswer(String a) {
    answer = a;
}

public void setPoints(int p) {
    points = p;
}

}
```

Driver.java

```
public class Driver {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Trivia[] t = new Trivia[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        t[i] = new Trivia();
    }

    t[0].setQuestion("How many states are in the US?");
    t[0].setAnswer("50");
    t[0].setPoints(1);

    t[1].setQuestion("Who is the richest person in the US");
    t[1].setAnswer("You");
    t[1].setPoints(1);

    t[2].setQuestion("How many senators come from each state?");
    t[2].setAnswer("2");
    t[2].setPoints(2);

    t[3].setQuestion("What is the largest state?");
    t[3].setAnswer("Alaska");
    t[3].setPoints(2);

    t[4].setQuestion("Who was the thrid president?");
    t[4].setAnswer("Thomas Jefferson");
    t[4].setPoints(3);

    ObjectOutputStream outputStream = null;

    try {
        outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("C:\\Work\\workspace\\aman\\src\\trivia\\trivia.dat"));

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Could not open file");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    try {
        outputStream.writeObject(t);
        outputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Writing error");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    ArrayList<Trivia> triviaQuestions = new ArrayList<Trivia>();

    try {
        ObjectInputStream  inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("C:\\Work\\workspace\\aman\\src\\trivia\\trivia.dat"));

        for(int i=0; i<5; i++){ // Repeats the content of the loop five times
        triviaQuestions.add((Trivia) inputStream.readObject());
        }
        inputStream.close(); // Closes the input stream because it is not longer needed


    } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("File not found.");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    Trivia yourRandomTrivia = triviaQuestions.get((new Random()).nextInt(triviaQuestions.size())); // This will be your random question

}

// You did not get an auto complete suggestion because you typed outside of a method


}
```

noe when I try to run this program, I get an error saying "Ltrivia.Trivia; cannot be cast to trivia.Trivia". The error is thrown in class Driver on line " triviaQuestions.add((Trivia) inputStream.readObject());". I did some research on this and found that 'L' means array of a datatype. But, I have simple created an arrayList of type Trivia and trying to add each element I get from the inputStream by casting them to Trivia class.
Does anybody have any suggestions on this?

Answer (score 2):

Your code is writing an **Array** of Trivia objects.

Then you try to read and add that to a **list** of Trivia objects.

You cant add arrays of Trivia to an List of Trivia!

And that is what the message is telling you: you cant cast the type Trivia[] to Trivia. Because an array of X is not the same as a single X.

One solution: instead of writing t as a whole, you can simply iterate t and write the members of the array. Of course that means that you have to somehow remember how many elements you wrote into that stream. You could get there by *first* writing an Integer object representing the number of Trivia objects that will follow.

The other solution: just read back that Trivia[]; and iterate it then; to add the various Trivia objects one by one.

Edit: on your comment: when you read from an ObjectInputStream you get back **those** things that you put into your file/stream earlier on. As said: your code puts a *single* object of type ARRAY of Trivia into bytes ... and then you want to read that thing back as a single Trivia object! That does not work!

Comment: what does: triviaQuestions.add((Trivia) inputStream.readObject());
returns? This is just returning a single Trivia element right?